# Is efficiency the same as performance?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a difference between [efficiency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) and [performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)? “Performance” feels like it's specifically about execution speed; “efficiency” could be about [memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487/ubuntu-how-do-you-free-up-resources) or [disk space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2027/how-do-i-minimize-disk-space-usage) or other resources.

In any case, the four questions tagged [efficency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficency) must be retagged, to fix the spelling. Should they be retagged to [efficiency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) or [performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)? Should [efficiency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) and [performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) be synonyms?

Comment: are these tags really useful?

Comment: @xenoterracide Yes, it's useful to easily search for questions that are about performance/efficiency, and [tag:performance] has a few followers. What I don't know is if there's a need to distinguish between the various kinds of efficiency, or what the best name is.

Comment: I went ahead and retagged some of those.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I'm not too concerned either way, but I'll vote for making [efficiency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) a synonym of [performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)

Answer (score 3):

Efficiency is about appropriateness of resource consumption. Performance is about speed of execution. They are similar, but slightly different, concepts. Using the minimum CPU and memory to get a particular job done within the time constraints may be the most efficient way to do the job, but it won't provide the highest performance.

Most likely, people are tagging questions [efficiency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) when they mean [performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance). There aren't that many real questions about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency can be about memory usage, or power consumption, but performance can be used for that purpose too, while most questions are about speed of execution.